# Auto uploading files into a temp folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, file-upload

How can I get my controller method to be called automatically after choosing a file from the file dialog without a submit so I can then save that file in a temp folder until user is ready to save and store the file to file system. Is this approach ideal? I goal is to eventually let a user to upload a short video, save it to temp folder, let him/her see a thumbnail in the view and he/she wants they can save it to there profile.

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/Home/UploadFiles" method="POST" 
               enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="fileupload" type="file" onchange="uploadSelectedFile(this)" 
               name="file">
  @*<input type="submit" />*@
</form>
```

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     //Save file to temp folder 
     //then later user can call a save button to acutally save the files.
     return Json();
}
```

Comment: hey I updated my answer. Seems like you have to do ` Request.Files["Filedata"];` with uploadify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**:  Apparently uploadify sends it's files with the key "Filedata". I wrote an [article here with a full asp.net-mvc/uploadify sample](http://gideondsouza.com/blog/ajax-upload-files-with-asp.net-mvc-and-uploadify).

---

I don't think you can rely on a regular file upload.

You would have to do an ajax upload in the back as soon as the user uploads the file. See [this link](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/) for some off the shelf controls you can use.

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) seems pretty promising and is a **JQuery plugin**. This is how you would do it with uploadify:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />

$(function() {
    $("#file_upload").uploadify({
        'swf'      : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '<path_to_your_action_method>' //Youcontroller/UploadFiles
    });
});
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles()
{
     //Uploadify sends this as "Filedata"
     HttpPostedFile theFile = Request.Files["Filedata"];
     //save your file here...

     //anything you return will be sent to the onUploadSucess event
     http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/
     return Json();
}
```

When the user then chooses save you can figure whether he saved a file with some association to the user and transfer the file to a proper location.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This is the first time I've fooled with uploading files. In the controller method, when you call Request.Files["file_upload"], this is the name of the input from the view?

Comment: So this is just another way to get the selected files rather than getting them from a passed parameter. Never new I could do this. Appreciate it.

Comment: @TMan Yep. Putting stuff in the parameters is just nice syntactic sugar asp.net-mvc gives you. The `Request`property (on the controller) gives you a [HttpRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_properties.aspx) object which gives you everything that came in the request. `Request.Form` for form data, `Request.QueryString` and `Request.Files`

Comment: Another question, is Request.FIles[] only available in .NET4.5 ? I Can't seem to find a reference to call this.

Comment: Any idea why request.file[] would be returning a null value?

Comment: I got it..I needed to change ["file_upload"] to ["formData"]

Comment: @TMan Are you sure? It's `Request.Files`, Plural. Check the names, also open your browser debugger and check whether the file is going through in the header. Also, the property has been there since .NET1.1 See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest_properties(v=vs.71).aspx). You will be able to access it from the controller via a property. (i.e. this.Request.Files (inside the controller))

Comment: Yea I had to do ths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869334/request-files-keep-returning-null

Answer (score 1):

As `gideon` said i think you cannot do this with normal file upload.

you can do this using `Uploadify` file upload control.

```
 $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                'checkExisting': 'Content/uploadify/check-exists.php',
                'swf': '/Content/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                'uploader': '/Home/uploadify',
                'auto': false,
                'buttonText': 'Browse'
});
```

and the code in controller is

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Uploadify(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileData)
        {
            foreach (var file in fileData)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    currpath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP"), file.FileName);

                    file.SaveAs(currpath);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

If you are uploading single file use `HttpPostedFileBase` instead of `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back Karthik, I really appreciate both answers given by you and gideon. If I could choose two best answers I would, since gideon commented first I gave it to him. Appreciate the help, there are so many different widgets out there to upload files, it's hard to find the right one(and one that works in all browsers). I'll go ahead and give uploadify a look though. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't matter to whose reply you have marked as answer. You could get out of the issue that you posted here, that what matters