# Request.Files[""] Keep returning null

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, uploadify

Using uploadify to auto submit a users files, in my controller method Request.Files["Name"] keeps returning null but request.form isn't null, I can see the file in request.form when I set a breakpoint and debug it. Am I missing something? I'm testing this on mvc2 but i plan on using it on mvc4.

```
<link href="../../Content/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.uploadify.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'swf': '/Content/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader': '/Home/UploadFile',
            'auto': true


            // Your options here
        });
    });
</script>
 </head>
   <body>           
   <%--<% using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post,
 new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 { %>--%>
  <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" style="margin-bottom: 0px" />

 <%-- <% } %>--%>
```

Controller Method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {           
        var theFile = Request.Files["file_upload"];
        return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

If I add a submit button and then submit it it will work though. I need to be auto though without a submit button.

Comment: I'm not familiar with uploadify. However, it appears that when you have the form, you are explicitly using the POST method and the action method is only responding to POST request. Is it possible that uploadify is doing a GET???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC `Uploadify` uses `fileData` as parameter. So:

```
var theFile = Request.Files["fileData"];
```

or even better:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
{          
    // The fileData parameter should normally contain the uploaded file
    // so you don't need to be looking for it in Request.Files
    return Json("Success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Of course if you are not happy with this name you could always customize it using the [`fileObjName`](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/fileobjname/) setting.

Comment: ah yea your right. Thanks. I didn't see anything about having to do that in their tutorials. Appreciate it. Why is it like this though?

Comment: Well, they had to pick some default value to send the file under, hadn't they? Why they picked `fileData` instead of `foo_bar_baz` is a difficult to answer question. As you know in the [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) specification (which you have undoubtedly already read and are familiar with if you are doing web development) each uploaded file is associated an unique key that the server could use to retrieve from the request.

Comment: Yea I'm new to file uploading in web development..I've done it in desktop development which is more strait forward